# Rails 4.2.x - zero size uploaded files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, file-upload

I am having a problem with displaying uploaded images in views. IMO due to zero size for each uploaded file in `/public/uploads`.

Currently trying to get a grasp in uploading and serving files **without any ruby/rails gem**.

For this I ran a primitive app with basic scaffold just for testing upload/save cycle:

schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151104043709) do

  create_table "uploads", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "filename"
    t.string   "content_type"
    t.binary   "content"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

end
```

UploadsController#create:

```
  def create
    @upload = Upload.new(upload_params)
    data = params[:upload][:file]

    File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', data.original_filename), 'wb') do |f|
      f.write(data.read)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @upload.save
        format.html { redirect_to @upload, notice: 'Upload was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @upload }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @upload.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

model Upload.rb :

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
    include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
    attr_accessor :upload

    def file=(upload_data)
        self.filename = upload_data.original_filename
        self.content_type = upload_data.content_type
        self.content = upload_data.read
    end

    def filename=(new_filename)
        write_attribute("filename", sanitize_filename(new_filename))
    end

private

    def sanitize_filename(filename)
        just_filename = File.basename(filename)
        just_filename.gsub(/[^\w\.\-]/, '_')
    end
end
```

uploads#show view:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Filename:</strong>
  <%= @upload.filename %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Content type:</strong>
  <%= @upload.content_type %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= image_tag "/public/uploads/#{@upload.filename}" %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_upload_path(@upload) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', uploads_path %> | 
<%= link_to 'Download', download_path(id: @upload) %>
```

**PROBLEM:** what is not going well is that all the files get 0 bytes in `/public/uploads` dir.

and view renders like this:
[image]

index view:
[image]

and Failed to load image example:
[image]

and prove that all files are zero bytes:
[image]

**NOTICE:** binary should work correctly, because it is possible to dwnl each of the files with `send_data`:

```
  def download
    send_data(@upload.content,
              filename: @upload.filename,
              content_type: @upload.content_type,
              )
  end
```

+
[image]

===========================================
**Question:** what is not OK with the app and how to fix it to display image or images in view? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: HTML markup for image_tag in view:

`<img src="/public/uploads/61.JPG" alt="61" />`

Comment: use one of the gems. seriously. paperclip. carrierwave. do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing up two different methods of storing files:

1. Storing as a Binary Blob in your Database (ex: the `content` column in your DB)
2. Saving the file to the filesystem (ex: `/public/uploads/` )

Your implementation does a little bit of both: You're definitely saving the file as binary in the `content` column of the `uploads` table, and you're saving *something* to the filesystem. You need to pick one or the other.

If you want to use **Method 2 (Filesystem)**, it's gonna take a *bit* more work to get it going. If this is what you really want to do, let me know and I can edit my answer with a solution.

However, you're already pretty much there with **Method 1 (Database)**. We just need to put the pieces together in a slightly different way.

### Method 1: Storing Binary Blob in Database

You mentioned that `send_data` was working for you—that's exactly what we're going to use to fix your problem.

First, add a method to `UploadsController`

```
def show_image
  @upload = Upload.find(params[:id])
  send_data @upload.content, type: @upload.content_type, disposition: 'inline'
end
```

Next, add a corresponding route to `routes.rb`

```
get 'show_image', to: 'uploads#show_image'
```

And finally, in your view, `/uploads/show.html.erb`, swap out your `image_tag` for this one

```
<%= image_tag url_for(controller: "uploads", action: "show_image", id: @upload.id) %>
```

And there we go. That should be enough for it to work.

We basically defined a controller action to grab the binary blob from the database, which then uses `send_data` with the `'inline'` disposition to return the file to your view with the correct MIME type so that the `link_tag` in your view knows what to do with it.

You'll notice that you can delete almost everything in the `create` method of your `UploadsController`. All you need is the standard boilerplate code:

```
def create
  @upload = Upload.new(upload_params) # <-- All you need

  respond_to do |format|
  ...
end
```

You can also remove the `/public/uploads` directory because you're not using it. The file is stored completely in the database with this method and will not appear in your filesystem.

Hope this was helpful! Let me know if this works for you.

---

Note about **Method 2 (Filesystem)**:

I'm guessing you're doing this as a learning experience, which is great, but if you're ever trying to store uploaded files in the filesystem on a "real" app, you *really* should use a gem to handle it. [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) make things really easy and is a useful tool even in production applications where you're ultimately storing files somewhere else like S3, so it's definitely not a waste to learn it.

### Method 2 – Storing File in Filesystem

Okay, so it turns out that your code for the filesystem work was actually pretty close to working. The main problem was that in the `file=(upload_data)` method of `upload.rb`, you called `upload_data.read`. Then, in `UploadsController#create`, you call `f.write(data.read)`. The important thing to note here is that `data` and `upload_data` are the same exact file stream. Why is that important?

Well, the thing about `read` in Ruby (and most other file-reading methods) is that there is hidden mutable state that keeps track of the current "position" in the contents of the file stream. (This is useful because most file-reading is done in batches, like `foreach` which reads files one line at a time.) So what `file.read` *really* does is that it "reads the rest of the file". If your "position" is at the beginning, then "the rest of the file" is the entire file. But if you're halfway through, then "the rest" is just the second half. Because of this, the "current position" always end up at the very end of the file when it's done `read`-ing, meaning that (unless we "rewind") any future calls to `read` will return the empty string because there is no more "rest of the file". Example:

```
myfile = File.open(some_path_to_file, 'r')
myfile.read
  # => "lorem ipsum..." # (file contents from beginning)
myfile.read
  # => ""  # (empty string)
myfile.rewind
  # => 0 (resets 'position' to position 0, the beginning)
myfile.read
  # => "lorem ipsum..." # (file contents from beginning)
```

(Okay, so that's enough information for you to crack the problem if you want to give it a try before reading the answer. If not, or when you're ready, read on...)

**Solution**

In `upload.rb`, make the following change file=(upload_data)

```
def file=(upload_data)
  self.filename = upload_data.original_filename
  self.content_type = upload_data.content_type
  self.content = upload_data.read # <-- Either Delete this line, OR
  upload_data.rewind              # <-- Add this line
end
```

Obviously in a real app, we'd delete the `self.content` line because we're trying to implement Method 2, using the filesystem, but since this is a test app, you can totally have both working at the same time. To do that, just add the `upload_data.rewind` line at the very end.

So now the `create` method should be successfully adding the files to your `/public/uploads` directory (they won't be empty anymore) so check to make sure that's working. Next, we just have to make sure the views are set up properly.

In `show.rb` the image tag should look like this

```
<%= image_tag "/uploads/#{@upload.filename}" %>
```

You had `/public/uploads/...` instead of `/uploads/...`. For security reasons, `image_tag` can only look inside `/public`, so you don't have to specify '/public' in the path—it will get added automatically.

And, we're done! Let me know if it works for you.

**More**

There are a few more things you probably *should* do. Like modify the `create` action slightly:

```
File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', data.original_filename), 'wb') do |f|
  f.write(data.read)
  f.close # <-- add this line. You should always explicitly close file streams after you open them.
end

#### something else here
```

Also, instead of hard-coding the paths like we did, store the path in the database in a `file_path` column and then we can just pass `@upload.file_path` to our `image_tag`.

```
rails g migration AddFilePathToUploads file_path:string
rake db:migrate
```

And then make sure our `create` action manually sets the path before saving. So plug the following in instead of "something else here"

```
@upload.file_path = ['/uploads', data.original_filename].join '/'
```

Then change the image tag in `show.rb`

```
<%= image_tag @upload.file_path %>
```

Alright, *now* we're done. I just want to make the recommendation once again to check out the Paperclip or CarrierWave gems, since they're what you'll likely be using for any real project.

I hope you learned something and that this was helpful to you. I had fun with it too. Let me know when you get it working!

Cheers

Comment: OMG!!! It works!!! Method1 works!!! :)
I spent whole 3 days searching the Internet for solution and now i got it!
@Sherlock_HJ many thanks!!

Comment: could you please give some notes on how to deal with **Method 2 (Filesystem).**

Comment: You're welcome! And yeah, I'll update my answer with how to do it through the filesystem. I might not have time until tomorrow though.

Comment: Alright @Trakaitisguesthouse, Method 2 is up! Let me know how it goes.

Comment: method 1 & 2 works perfectly. Thank you!

All of these points seems so familiar when you point them, but I somehow manage to forget them and get frustrated when it comes to implement something new independently with no manuals or supervision. Hope it is due to lack of practise :)

Comment: Nice. Yeah, it all comes with practice. My recommendation to you at this point is, before you start to implement something, take out a piece of paper or open a note file and write out the high-level "pseudocode" of your algorithm. Then, you can get more and more specific on each piece until you have real code. That'll keep you from making mistakes like mixing up the filesystem with database tables. Anyway, good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, i think this should help.

```
original_filename =  data.original_filename.to_s
tmp = data.tempfile
file = File.join("public/uploads", original_filename)
FileUtils.cp tmp.path, file
```

Comment: when replaced your suggested code with original one in def file=(uploaded_data) -> instance is created but with blank data in filename, content_type  and binary.

am I right that this had to be put in:

`def file=(upload_data)
  new_filename =  upload_data.original_filename.to_s
  tmp = upload_data.tempfile
  file = File.join("public", "uploads", new_filename)
  FileUtils.cp tmp.path, file
 end`

Comment: Also when trying to dwnl this file it show 0 bytes in zise, so binary is also not OK upon instance create

Comment: you need to replace this in your controller not in model. replace this with `File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', data.original_filename), 'wb') do |f|
      f.write(data.read)
    end
`

Comment: I also added my previous code:

`self.filename = new_filename`
`self.content_type = upload_data.content_type`
`self.content = upload_data.read`

Now instances are created, filename, MIME, binary are OK, no zero bytes files in `/public/uploads`.. BUT.. no image display in views

Comment: check the filename stored in database and name of the uploaded file at `public/uploads`